# How can i checked collection_check_boxes by the other object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had my collection_check_boxes like this.

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:car_insurance_object_model,
                                                   :car_model_id,
                                                   car_model_each_brand ,
                                                   :id,:code_name) do |b|
    b.label { b.check_box + b.text }
end %>
```

It can be displayed correctly like this.

[image]

But i want some of it to be checked if it is already in my many to many table of my car_insurance_object and car_model table.

So how can i checked that collection_check_boxes by my @selected_model object

```
@selected_model = @car_insurance_object.car_models
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you're after here? What is the expected result? What have you tried? What 'doesn't work'?

Comment: i already added more details.